# create method not available in ArrayListMultimap

Tags: java, guava

I am trying to use Guava Library's implementation of MultiMap. According to the 
[Guava API Docs](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) it has a static `create()` method, but my Eclipse IDE thinks it doesn't even though I have imported the required jar.

It suggests `The method create() is undefined for the type ArrayListMultimap`

Screen Shot for same:

[image]

Comment: What version of Guava are you using?  Have you tried rebuilding the project?

Comment: I've tried recreating your problem and I can't get the same error, that method does exist. My initial thought was that the method was not in your version of the library, but that method exists in the latest version and all earlier versions that I can locate. I think you'll need to post more information - which jar file are you using, for example.

Comment: @Trisha i am using google-collections-0.8.jar .

Comment: Ah, that's what your problem is - Guava is not the same at the Google collections library. You want guava instead: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava

Comment: @Trisha yes even i realised that. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Trisha make that an answer, you should get points for that..

Comment: @Eugene good point, done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Google Collections is not the same as Guava, although they share many of the same classes. That `create` method is only available if you use a Guava jar rather than google-collections-0.8.jar

You can download the Guava jar (of any version) from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava, or alternatively get the Maven/Gradle config from the same place.